# Responsive photo galery grid (css)

Tags: css, gallery

I'm coding a personal website with a photo galery. I'd like it responsive but it doesn't work as I'd like. An example would be in this website (https://tiffany-tourn.fr/).

Here is my html:

```
<section id="galerie">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Galerie photos</h3>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="myGalery">
                    <img class="gallery_item_1" src="images/fondecran.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid gallery_item_2" src="images/modele.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid gallery_item_3" src="images/Photo4.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid gallery_item_4" src="images/Photo6.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid gallery_item_5" src="images/photo7.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid gallery_item_6" src="images/photo1.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid gallery_item_7" src="images/photo9.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid gallery_item_8" src="images/photo10.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid gallery_item_9" src="images/photo11.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid gallery_item_10" src="images/photo12.jpg"> 
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and here is the css

```
#galerie .container {
max-width: 800px;
width: 90vw;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
grid-auto-rows: 150px;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
grid-auto-flow: dense;
```

}

```
#galerie .container .myGalery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 5vw);
    grid-gap: 2px;
}

#galerie img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
}

.gallery_item_1 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 4;
}

.gallery_item_2 {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 4;
}

.gallery_item_3 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 4;
}

.gallery_item_7 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 8;
}

.gallery_item_8 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 5;
}

.gallery_item_9 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 5;
    grid-row-end: 6;
}

.gallery_item_10 {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 5;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 8;
}
```

I feel I'm not too far from it but it seems it lacks something!!! I'd like to have four columns for big screens and as the screen becomes smaller, I'd like 3 columns, 2 and then 1. I found the css property column-count but don't know how to properly implement it in my code.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@media`:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  your_class_or_id {
     column-count: 3;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  your_class_or_id {
     column-count: 2;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  your_class_or_id {
     column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

`max-width: ...px` - set how you need

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For those who would like a responsive photo gallery, I found this CSS code that works for me

```
#id or .class {
line-height: 0;
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-webkit-column-gap:   3px;
-moz-column-count:    4;
-moz-column-gap:      3px;
column-count:         4;
column-gap:           3px;
```

}

```
#id or .class img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto
}
```

and then simply add your media queries:

```
    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #id or .class {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #id or .class {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #id or .class {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  #id or .class {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help anyway ;)